# How to pass null value to select in plsql

Tags: java, plsql

I am trying to select some values in my table but when `Invoicedate` is null I got exception please help me!

**my code :**

```
query="select vend_name,vend_no from account where inv_date = '"+Invoicedate+"' or vend_no = "+Vendorno+" LIMIT 500";
```

please give any possible answer to me.

Comment: Can you explain your requirement in more detail

Comment: of course you get an exception when you pass null. what are you expecting?

Comment: IIRR the correct spell for Oracle is `foo is NULL`

Comment: I suspect your exception (which you haven't included in your question, for some reason) is due to the `LIMIT 500` bit, which is not supported in Oracle (versions prior to 12c).

Answer (score 1):

That's because in your code it will become `inv_date = 'null'` not `inv_date is null`.

You need to do `inv_date "+(Invoiceddate==null?"is null":"= '"+Invoiceddate+"'")+" or`

In general this is a bad way to do things though as you are open to SQL injection attacks and all sorts of other similar problems.

Use a `PreparedStatement` and all this will be handled for you:

```
PreparedStatement query = connection.prepareStatement("select vend_name,vend_no from account where inv_date = ? or vend_no = ? LIMIT ?");
query.setDate(1, Invoicedate);
... etc
```

Note also that you should follow the Java style conventions in variable naming etc, it will help people work with your code.

Comment: Also note `that = NULL` will not find NULL dates see [Nulls](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements005.htm#SQLRF30037)

Comment: True, the comparison should probably be "is null".